# Errors while verifying public keys in pgp (bitcoin core 26 / ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, pgp, release-verification

Following the [official how-to](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/) (step #6) and trying to verify bitcoin-26.0 release signature, I'm unable to import any of the [builder keys](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/tree/main/builder-keys) I download.

For example on `gpg --import achow101.gpg`, I get

```
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=7b)
gpg: read_block: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: import from 'achow101.gpg' failed: Invalid keyring
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Does anyone had the same issue? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Many thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. My steps were: 1. go to the [key file](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/blob/main/builder-keys/achow101.gpg) of achow101, 2. click "Download raw file" button, 3. `gpg --import Downloads/achow101.gpg` which succeeded. This machine runs Ubuntu 23.04, but I don’t expect that to be the issues. How did you acquire the file?

Comment: Great, could you please write that as an answer post instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] I got the file with `wget https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/blob/main/builder-keys/achow101.gpg`. That's my error here, the correct link is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/main/builder-keys/achow101.gpg`. Thank you [Murch](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/5406/murch) for your answer!